# File tree on PHP page using frames?

Tags: php, file, tree

I currently have a php webpage. However, I want to break it down into two sections and have a file browser on the left hand side of the page. I want the browser to be like a tree , so that a user can go deep into folders.

When a user browses down to a file and clciks it on the left side, I want that path `/dir1/dir2/file` to be loaded onto a text box that I have on the right hand side of my PHP page.

Can someone recommend going about this? I really feel overwhelmed and am too stressed out to begin. I was looking at file tree programs online and I come across paid one's or one's that there is no way I could integrate with my existing page, since they are pretty much file/upload browsers! I just want to have a tree structure without allowing the user to rename/upload

This is how I see the page being completed :

```
==========================
File Tree | Actual Page  |
File Tree | Actual Page  |
File Tree | Actual Page  |
File Tree | Actual Page  |
File Tree | Actual Page  |
File Tree | Actual Page  |
File Tree | Actual Page  |
==========================
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest coupling ajax to this, for a slightly snappier feel.

Comment: Norton commander clone, eh? Nice. As for the tree itself, you should simply iterate over the directory (`readdir`) and print everything out in nested `<ul><li>` lists. My advise is to use plain HTML with unclosed `<li>` tags this time. (Nesting is weird otherwise.) You can style that up easily with CSS to get the impression of a tree, e.g. http://odyniec.net/articles/turning-lists-into-trees/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could go about this. One way would be to have the file browser in an iframe and the file display in another iframe.

The filebrowser.php source would look very basically like this:

```
$dir = $_GET['dir'];

// validate $dir to make sure it's viewable by the current user!

$contents = scandir($dir);
foreach ($contents as $c) {
  $subfile = $dir.'/'.$c;
  if (is_dir($subfile) {
    echo "<a href=\"filebrowser.php?dir=".urlencode($subfile)."\" target=\"filebrowser_iframe\">$c</a><br>";
  } else {
    echo "<a href=\"filedisplay.php?file=".urlencode($subfile)."\" target=\"filedisplay_iframe\">$c</a><br>";
  }
}
```

In filedisplay.php

```
$file = $_GET['file'];

// validate $file to make sure it's viewable by the current user!

readfile($file);
```